# Switchable templates for a Canvas

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

Im new here and might aswell warn people that my english is not my primary langauge. 
Im currently trying to learn WPF and XAML, and right now im trying to make some sort of Paint program.

I have all the background code working (programming after MVVM) where my WM have a property name draw which contains information like X1,X2,Y1,Y2, **ElementType**, ect. All information needed to draw on a canvas. My idea was that I would have diffrent templates in the XAML code for different **ElementTypes** (so to keep the code behind a clean as possible) IE if ElementType = *Line* it would draw a line or of ElementType = *Textbox* a textbox would be inserted on the canvas.

I've searched alot around the net for diffrent ways to do it. But the only answer I've found is from this site and it only enables me to draw lines not select between diffrent templates. I might be searching for the wrong information or it might not be possible i dont know but now I'm trying to ask :)

So is there someone here who could guide me in the right direction or make a simple example in XAML of how to do it with two templates. It would be much appreciated

Hope any of this makes sense

Thank you

/Ephreal

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is a panel and we cannot change its Child template as we can do in an ItemsControl. For your app. you have to insert a textbox into Canvas (add as a child) in correct mouse position if ElementType is TextBox.

You can make use of Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top to place textbox properly in mouse position.

Regards,

Jawahar